# How to get twitter user name from request.env["omniauth.auth"] (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am using Omni auth in my application.
I could able to recieve token and secret by using below code..

```
auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
@token = auth['credentials']['token']
@secret = auth['credentials']['secret']
```

but i am stuck with getting the user name of the twitter account.
is it possible for me to get user name from this?

meanwhile i am searching for solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. The username can be fetched by using `auth['info']['name']`
I tried printing the return in Json format and can able to find this.

Comment: This seems to be the real name (e.g. "Mathias Panzenböck") and not the twitter user name (e.g. "@bloodyalbatross"). How do you get the latter?

Comment: Ah, that would be `auth['info']['nickname']`.